# Element static on React App with with react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

i've a question, it s possible have a static component on react app with react router, example, on my App i've this

```
<Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/"  render={(routeProps ) => <Home  data={props.data} isPeddingHome={props.isPeddingHome} onGetShows={props.onGetShows}  {...routeProps} />}/>
        <Route path="/movies" render={(routeProps) => <MoviesPage isPeddingMovies={props.isPeddingMovies} movies={props.movies} onGetMovies={props.onGetMovies} {...routeProps} /> }/>
        <Route path="/tvSeries" render={(routeProps) => <TvSeriesPage  isPeddingSeries={props.isPeddingSeries} series={props.series} onGetSeries={props.onGetSeries} {...routeProps}/>}/>
        <Route path="/tv/:id"  render={(routeProps) => <TvDettailsRoute key={routeProps.match.params.id} {...routeProps}/>}/>
        <Route path="/movie/:id"  render={(routeProps) => <MovieDettailsRouter key={routeProps.match.params.id}  {...routeProps}/>}/>
        <Route path="/register" render={(routeProps) => <Register />} />
        <Route path="/login" render={(routeProps) => <Login /> } />
      </Switch>
 </Router>
```

and on every component i've call the header, can have i a situasion like this?

```
<header>
 <Header />
 <Search />
</header>
<Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/"  render={(routeProps ) => <Home  data={props.data} isPeddingHome={props.isPeddingHome} onGetShows={props.onGetShows}  {...routeProps} />}/>
            <Route path="/movies" render={(routeProps) => <MoviesPage isPeddingMovies={props.isPeddingMovies} movies={props.movies} onGetMovies={props.onGetMovies} {...routeProps} /> }/>
            <Route path="/tvSeries" render={(routeProps) => <TvSeriesPage  isPeddingSeries={props.isPeddingSeries} series={props.series} onGetSeries={props.onGetSeries} {...routeProps}/>}/>
            <Route path="/tv/:id"  render={(routeProps) => <TvDettailsRoute key={routeProps.match.params.id} {...routeProps}/>}/>
            <Route path="/movie/:id"  render={(routeProps) => <MovieDettailsRouter key={routeProps.match.params.id}  {...routeProps}/>}/>
            <Route path="/register" render={(routeProps) => <Register />} />
            <Route path="/login" render={(routeProps) => <Login /> } />
          </Switch>
     </Router>
```

with the Router only call the component thath change ?

edit: I want to have a header always static on the website, then with route load the component in base the path, this so i don't need to load the hader for every component

Comment: Question is not self explaining. pls elaborate.

Comment: This is possible, yes.